# My new home page(after multistore setup) is loading without template config

Tags: magento-1

I just setup(magento 1.7.0.2) my installation to work with another store(subdomain from main store)
I think that almost all configs are ok because when a type my new store2 link on the brownser the new home page is showed but it's "naked", can't load style/template.
Can averyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Thanks in advance ;)
Carlos

Answer (score 0):

try with :

Login to ssh, go to magento directory for instance i’m

cd /var/www/html/magento

1- rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/*  var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/composer_home/cache/*

2- sudo chmod 777 var -R & sudo chmod 777 pub -R pub

i hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for help,
Can I use ftp service? I don't know how to use ssh :/ sorry

Comment: I just check the path permission using cpanel-file manager  and all is ok :/

Comment: Solved, the problem was in store view :/

Comment: you welcome ,I'm happy to got the solution?